# Why does this code decompress a UIImage so much better than the naive approach?

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uiimage

In my app I need to load large JPEG images and display them in a scroll view. In order to keep the UI responsive, I decided to load the images in the background, then display them on the main thread. In order to fully load them in the background, I force each image to be decompressed. I *was* using this code to decompress an image (note that my app is iOS 7 only, so I understand that using these methods on a background thread is OK):

```
+ (UIImage *)decompressedImageFromImage:(UIImage *)image {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, YES, 0);
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    UIImage *decompressedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return decompressedImage;
}
```

However, I still had long load times, UI stutter, and a lot of memory pressure. I just found [another solution](http://ioscodesnippet.com/2011/10/02/force-decompressing-uiimage-in-background-to-achieve/):

```
+ (UIImage *)decodedImageWithImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
    // System only supports RGB, set explicitly and prevent context error
    // if the downloaded image is not the supported format
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                 CGImageGetWidth(imageRef),
                                                 CGImageGetHeight(imageRef),
                                                 8,
                                                 // width * 4 will be enough because are in ARGB format, don't read from the image
                                                 CGImageGetWidth(imageRef) * 4,
                                                 colorSpace,
                                                 // kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little
                                                 // makes system don't need to do extra conversion when displayed.
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    if ( ! context) {
        return nil;
    }
    CGRect rect = (CGRect){CGPointZero, CGImageGetWidth(imageRef), CGImageGetHeight(imageRef)};
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, imageRef);
    CGImageRef decompressedImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    UIImage *decompressedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:decompressedImageRef];
    CGImageRelease(decompressedImageRef);
    return decompressedImage;
}
```

This code is orders of magnitude better. The image loads almost immediately, there is no UI stutter, and the memory usage has gone way down.

So my question is two-fold:

1. Why is the second method so much better than the first?
2. If the second method is better because of the unique parameters of the device, is there a way to ensure that it will work equally well for all iOS devices, present and future? I wouldn't want to assume a native bitmap format that changes on me, reintroducing this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that you're running this on a Retina device. In `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, you asked for the default scale, which is the scale of the main screen, which is 2. This means that it's generating a bitmap 4x as large. In the second function, you're drawing at 1x scale.

Try passing a scale of 1 to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and see if your performance is similar.

Comment: Brilliant. Yes, I am running on a retina device, and yes, setting scale=1 gives me similar performance and memory usage. I'll go with the first method now, since I expect it would do the right thing, whatever the device's characteristics.

Comment: To get the best of both worlds (speed and beauty, at the cost of more code), you may want to display a quick 1x render (or even a 0.5x render) and then come back and fill in a retina render later if the image is still on the screen. For an example, see https://github.com/iosptl/ios6ptl/tree/master/ch13/JuliaOp (this is from Chapter 13 of iOS 6 Programming Pushing the Limits; it'll be Chapter 9 in iOS 7 PTL when that comes out later this year.)

Comment: Changing UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to scale=1 makes an image render with very poor quality when up-scaling. The code using CGImage renders with high quality just like when no forced decompression is used.
Also, the UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions specified opaque and does not work with transparency