# CGBitmapInfo value performance on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, drawing, quartz-2d

I am drawing pieces of a CGBitmapContext in the drawRect of a UIView. What are the best CGBitmapInfo enum values to ensure that performance is optimal? Right now I am using `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big`, but I have also seen this stackoverflow question snippet which suggests an alternative:

[Why does this code decompress a UIImage so much better than the naive approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682804/why-does-this-code-decompress-a-uiimage-so-much-better-than-the-naive-approach)

```
// makes system don't need to do extra conversion when displayed.
kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little
```

My CGBitmapContext is mutable, so the user can draw on it, add images to it, etc.

Comment: As far as I know the second set of options if faster. But could you use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to create the bitmap context and don't worry about these details?

Comment: My CGBitmapContext is mutable, meaning the user can draw on it, add images to it, etc. and all these then need to be displayed on the screen using the UIView drawRect.

Comment: @yurish can you point me to documentation on why the second is faster?

Comment: I remember one Apple's WWDC video where they demonstrated simple drawing application that cached part of the drawing in UIImage. Probably WWDC 2012 "Optimizing 2D Graphics and Animation Performance" but I'm not sure. As for documentation - sorry I don't know if this documented elsewhere. I asked similar question on the Apple developer forum and the answer was AlphaFirst or AlphaNoneSkipFirst with LittleEndian or HostEndian (premultiplied)

Comment: I've found that kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little works well for my app and I remember reading it was optimized for the iPhone hardware...but I don't remember where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran tests with `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big` vs `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little` and the profiler did show me that there is a slightly different code path.

`kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little` copies memory directly, while `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big` goes through a conversion function.

This made almost no impact in the total time it took to draw paths in my `CGBitmapContext` (even on an iPod 4) and then call `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` to show them on screen. Furthermore since the overall times are essentially identical, I'm sticking with `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big`.

*EDIT*
I switched back to `kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little` in order to have better compatibility with other iOS frameworks (like AVFoundation) that use BGRA (little endian) byte orders since there was no impact on performance.

Comment: do you measurments of the total time include time to convert the bitmap from one format to the other?

Comment: Yes, the overall milliseconds were very close (maybe 10-20 difference). Perhaps I'll profile it again and post the exact timings.

Comment: How could you measure the conversion time? If I understand correctly this conversion is done when Core Animation transaction is commited. The setNeedsDisplayInRect: just marks the view for redrawing, the drawing itself happens later in the run loop cycle.

Comment: The profiler breaks out the percentage of each function call (even iOS framework calls). I simply selected a 1 second chunk of time while I was drawing with my finger using both bitmap info's.